# How to update a Table from Form data in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, patch

I have a form in Laravel5

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/song/Baby/update" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="kagIHsGe3zOZSPVyW6wW84Cn5eresZ2nlF287nNK">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="title" type="text" value="Baby">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="lyrics" cols="50" rows="10">
            Yo Yo Yo BABY
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Update Song">
    </div>        
</form>
```

Then in Route file I have written the code

```
patch('songs/Baby/update','SongsController@update');
```

Its throwing error

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:

Is the syntax changed for PATCH request in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 2):

Your route and form action are different.

You have defined a route with `songs` (plural) and used as `song` (singular) in form action.

Try changing your form action to

```
action="http://localhost:8000/songs/Baby/update"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` and `Route::put('songs/Baby/update','SongsController@update')`.

Comment: Okay I will check this one

Comment: check chanafdo's reply. I think he got it. You are missing a 's' in your form action.